# How to use order by with LENGTH() function

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to execute the following query but, every time i'm getting the wrong result and its returning total value 0 . Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
SELECT content, ((LENGTH(content)-(LENGTH(REPLACE(content,'oracle',''))))*4+(LENGTH(content)-(LENGTH(REPLACE(content,'finance',''))))*3+(LENGTH(content)-(LENGTH(REPLACE(content,'functional',''))))*2+(LENGTH(content)-(LENGTH(REPLACE(content,'consultant',''))))*1)
FROM `jobs` order by ((LENGTH(content)-(LENGTH(REPLACE(content,'oracle',''))))*4+(LENGTH(content)-(LENGTH(REPLACE(content,'finance',''))))*3+(LENGTH(content)-(LENGTH(REPLACE(content,'functional',''))))*2+(LENGTH(content)-(LENGTH(REPLACE(content,'consultant',''))))*1);
```

Comment: Hint to make your life easier. You can say `ORDER BY 2` to mean *order by the second column in the result set.*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the column index as:

```
SELECT content, ((LENGTH(content)-  
(LENGTH(REPLACE(content,'oracle',''))))*4+(LENGTH(content)-  
(LENGTH(REPLACE(content,'finance',''))))*3+(LENGTH(content)-
(LENGTH(REPLACE(content,'functional',''))))*2+(LENGTH(content)-
(LENGTH(REPLACE(content,'consultant',''))))*1)
FROM `jobs` ORDER BY 2;
```

Or by a column alias as:

```
SELECT content, ((LENGTH(content)-  
(LENGTH(REPLACE(content,'oracle',''))))*4+(LENGTH(content)-  
(LENGTH(REPLACE(content,'finance',''))))*3+(LENGTH(content)-
(LENGTH(REPLACE(content,'functional',''))))*2+(LENGTH(content)-
(LENGTH(REPLACE(content,'consultant',''))))*1) CONTENT_SIZE
FROM `jobs` ORDER BY CONTENT_SIZE;
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried 2nd query its working good but, its looks similar to my query then  what is the problem with my query?

Comment: You are welcome @PavanKarumuri, vote up my answer. I think the reason why yours didn't work is because the column name is too long.